# Нарушение фильтрации ввода в input после символа @

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть компонент InputEmail, по задумке он принимает только латиницу и символы "@", "-", "_", "."

Но есть такой баг: вводишь любой символ, затем "@" и после этого можно вводить кириллицу. В приведенном ниже коде наблюдается такой баг, попробуйте.

После кириллицы принимает и латиницу, вперемешку. Если введешь какой-либо из этих символов "@", "-", "*", ".", то кириллица отфильтровывается, остаются только нужные символы. Но, после данных символов можно опять вводить кириллицу, важно чтобы был любой символ между "@", "-", "*", ".", то опять можно будет вводить кириллицу, и опять новый символ "@", "-", "_", "." отфильтрует до нужного значения и так далее.

В чем может быть проблема и как это побороть?

```js
const InputEmail = () => {

// Сложный пример, показывающий, что дело не в регулярном выражении
const onChange = e => {
        e.currentTarget.value = [...e.currentTarget.value].filter(symbol => {
            let charCode = symbol.charCodeAt();
            return (

                // 0-9
                (charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57)
                ||

                // -
                (charCode === 45)
                ||

                // _
                (charCode === 95)
                ||

                // .
                (charCode === 46)
                ||

                // @ A-Z
                (charCode >= 64 && charCode <= 90)
                ||

                // a-z
                (charCode >= 97 && charCode <= 122)
            )
        }).join('');

    };

// Простой пример на регулярных выражениях
//    const onChange = e => e.currentTarget.value = e.currentTarget.value.match(/[a-zA-Z0-9@_.\-]*/g).join('');

    return (
        <div className="Input">
            <input
                type="email"
                placeholder="Электронная почта"
                onChange={onChange}

            />
            <label />
        </div>
    )
};

ReactDOM.render(
      <InputEmail />,
      document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Согласно этого регулярного выражения `/[a-zA-Z0-9@_.\-]*/g`, после `@` можно вводит любой символ. Это не баг, а неправильно составленное регулярное выражение

Comment: Ага... а как тогда составить правильно? Экранировать с помощью \ ?

Comment: Я в регулярных выражениях не силен. Где-то прочитал: "у Вас есть проблема и Вы решили использовать регулярные выражения - теперь у Вас 2 проблемы")

Comment: А где в регулярном написано, что любой символ? . ? \. не изменяет работу, баг остается, в конструкции [], насколько мне известно, . не означает любой символ, а означает именно точку. И в [] символы не задают последовательность. В противном случае можно было бы написать только латиницу, затем цифры, затем символы, но это работает не так

Comment: http://javascript.ru/basic/regular-expression+

Comment: К тому же я делал фильтрацию другим способом, с помощью .filter и charCodeAt, забивал проверку символов по их utf номеру. Там наблюдалась такая же ошибка, хотя там процесс был полностью подконтролен

Comment: Проблема в регулярном выражении. Дело в том, что порядок указания символов в `[]` не влияет на порядок в проверяемом тексте.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, а какое должно быть регулярное выражение в таком случае?

Comment: Я исправил код на фильтрацию вообще без регулярных выражений. Дело не в регулярных выражениях

Comment: Дебаг - наше всё. Реакт вставляет ponycode-сущности, которые, как известно, состоят из разрешённых Вами символов. Проверить можно взяв `value`. Например, `test@Привет` станет `test@xn--b1agh1afp`.

Comment: @Other, обалдеть! Интересно! А можно как-то преодолеть такое поведение?